# Multi-platform InputStream Alternative in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inputstream, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m looking for a multi-platform alternative to input streams. My concrete task is to fetch an encrypted file from a remote server via https and decrypt it on demand.

In Java land I would an implement `InputStream` which proxies the reads to the input stream from the https library. How can I do the same in kotlin targeting multiple platforms.

I see ktor returns an [ByteReadChannel](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-io/kotlinx-coroutines-io-js/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/io/ByteReadChannel.kt), but I don’t know which functions.

I’m lost and don’t know where to start. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 9):

If the framework you are using does not provide you with a full-fledged `InputStream` implementation, the only chance left is to write your own. Much like what the ktor developers did: `ByteReadChannel` is just an abstraction of "reading bytes from a channel". 
This abstraction lives in the common part and allows to write application and business logic around it.

The key to make this work in the context of a Kotlin Multiplatform project is, the actual implementation needs to be provided in the platform specific parts. The JVM specific code of the ktor project actually has an implementation that uses `InputStream`: [`InputStream.toByteReadChannel`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-io/kotlinx-coroutines-io-jvm/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/io/jvm/javaio/Reading.kt#L79).

You certainly don't have to do it like your example from the ktor project and model everything down from byte channels up to file representations. If you want to leverage Kotlin framework classes, [Sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html) might be handy. This could look something like this:

```
// in common
interface FileFetcher {
  fun fetch(): Sequence<Byte>
}

expect fun fileFetcher(source: String): FileFetcher

// in jvm
class JvmFileFetcher(val input: java.io.InputStream): FileFetcher {
  override fun fetch(): Sequence<Byte> = input.readBytes().asSequence()
}

actual fun fileFetcher(source: String): FileFetcher {
  val input = java.net.URL(source).openStream()
  return JvmFileFetcher(input)
}
```

You would define an interface `FileFetcher` along with a factory function `fileFetcher` in the common part. By using the `expect` keyword on the `fileFetcher` function you need to provide platform-specific implementations for all target platforms you define. Use the `FileFetcher` interface in the common part to implement your logic (decrypting file contents etc.). See the documentation for `Sequence` for how to work with it.

Then implement the factory function for all platforms and use the `actual` keyword on them. You will then need to write platform-specific implementations of `FileFetcher`. My example shows how a JVM version of the `FileFetcher` interface.

The example is of course very basic and you probably would not want to do it exactly like this (at least some buffering would be needed, I guess). Also, within the JVM part you could also leverage your favorite networking/HTTP library easily.